# How to pass a function callback to a created window? (Windows)

Tags: windows, callback

I've a function callback to handle the window's events like WM_SIZE. Now, how to pass the function callback to the open window?  (It's for a command-line application).

I've seen RegisterClassEx but I think that it's used at creating a new window.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know when a window has changed its size, so I created the function callback to handle it. Now, I need to pass it to the window where the program is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle windows messages for an existing window you have a couple options:

**Subclassing**. Each window has a "window proc" callback function (that you are referring to), and you can replace it using `SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC`. Then in your own window proc, you need to forward messages to the original one that you replaced. There are some limitations though:

1. You cannot safely un-subclass a window.
2. You can only do this within your own process.

**Windows hooks**, using `SetWindowsHookEx`. Use this if you want to peek into the messages of other windows - you can see all messages for windows in a given thread, or system-wide. There are different types of hooks that allow you to catch different types of messages. This is a pretty heavy approach; a last resort so you don't bog down the system unnecessarily.